# Unable to install Wine; Using instructions from WineHQ

Tags: wine

Here is a link showing my terminal. I can not install Wine and it is frustrating, Please offer some advice.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwy2S.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In elementary OS it is not possible to add PPAs by default. You need to enable this feature with `sudo apt install software-properties-common`

Comment: Okay so i did that, now its saying it cant install Wine due to broken held packages
https://imgur.com/D9xeL1r

Comment: Also got an error when trying to install from the app center https://imgur.com/WQTsviS

Comment: Try to update / dist-upgrade your system. There are a lot of not up to date packages. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`. Then also check if there is something written with broken packages. Try to run `sudo apt update --fix-missing` and then `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Which eOS are you using? Is it Juno? If so, you should use the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS link. `sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main' `

Comment: Yes it is Juno.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
```